# С#: передача параметров и данных POST запросом в формате multipart/form-datа

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Перепробовал уже различные варианты, собственно сам код:

```
var parameters = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("login","***"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password","***"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("get","***")
};

var data = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters);

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://ekinobilet.ru/ekbs/upload.aspx");
request.Method = "POST";

byte[] dataArray = await data.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
request.ContentLength = dataArray.Length;
request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data";

var dataStream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync();
dataStream.Write(dataArray, 0, dataArray.Length);
dataStream.Close();

var resp = await request.GetResponseAsync();
dataStream = resp.GetResponseStream();

Stream receiveStream = resp.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
var responseText = readStream.ReadToEnd();
```

Собственно само требование: Для загрузки содержимого папки «исходящие» с сервера ЕИС демонстратор фильмов направляет запрос по адресу в сети Интернет: https://ekinobilet.ru/ekbs/upload.aspx по HTTPS протоколу, метод: POST MIME-тип: multipart/form-data в соответствии с RFC1867 (http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1867.txt). Запрос должен содержать три параметра:
1) login (строка, ИМЯ ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЯ);
2) password (строка, ПАРОЛЬ);
3) XMLfile (файл, XML-документ).

Так как уже есть вопрос "С#: передача параметров с POST запросом", а вот нет ответа на решение более сложного варианта. Решил поменять вопрос на "С#: передача параметров и данных POST запросом в формате multipart/form-data".

Comment: 500 тая ошибка в ASP-NET самая тяжёлая, это означает что в ASP-NET возникло исключение. Ищите какой именно параметр не нравится или не достаёт ASP. Если хост ваш - запустите на тесте в режиме отладки. Или поставьте в web.config `<custom Errors mode="on">`, если чужое - только внимательно проверять параметры. ASP может шифровать параметры, делать валидацию сессии (нужно использовать куки, и обрабатывать все js-библиотеки, не валидная сессия = исключение).

Comment: Проверьте снифером передаваемые данные из браузера сайту, и из вашей программы сайту. По несовпадениям найдёте ошибку.

Comment: FormUrlEncodedContent разве означает multipart/form-data ? По моему нет. Надо ещё что-то дописать.

Comment: Заработало, поменял request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data" на application/x-www-form-urlencoded. И все заработало...

Comment: Теперь начал возвращать хоть какие то данные... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Забыл опубликовать решение данной задачи.

Первое, создал хэлпер класс Upload

```
public class Upload
{
    private static readonly Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    public static HttpWebResponse MultipartFormDataPost(string postUrl, Dictionary<string, object> postParameters)
    {
        string formDataBoundary = String.Format("----------{0:N}", Guid.NewGuid());
        string contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + formDataBoundary;

        byte[] formData = GetMultipartFormData(postParameters, formDataBoundary);

        return PostForm(postUrl, contentType, formData);
    }
    private static HttpWebResponse PostForm(string postUrl, string contentType, byte[] formData)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(postUrl) as HttpWebRequest;

        if (request == null)
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException("request is not a http request");
        }
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = contentType;
        request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        request.ContentLength = formData.Length;

        using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            requestStream.Write(formData, 0, formData.Length);
            requestStream.Close();
        }

        return request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
    }

    private static byte[] GetMultipartFormData(Dictionary<string, object> postParameters, string boundary)
    {
        Stream formDataStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        bool needsCLRF = false;

        foreach (var param in postParameters)
        {
            if (needsCLRF)
                formDataStream.Write(encoding.GetBytes("\r\n"), 0, encoding.GetByteCount("\r\n"));

            needsCLRF = true;

            if (param.Value is FileParameter)
            {
                FileParameter fileToUpload = (FileParameter)param.Value;
                string header = string.Format("--{0}\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{1}\"; filename=\"{2}\";\r\nContent-Type: {3}\r\n\r\n",
                    boundary,
                    param.Key,
                    fileToUpload.FileName ?? param.Key,
                    fileToUpload.ContentType ?? "application/octet-stream");

                formDataStream.Write(encoding.GetBytes(header), 0, encoding.GetByteCount(header));
                formDataStream.Write(fileToUpload.File, 0, fileToUpload.File.Length);
            }
            else
            {
                string postData = string.Format("--{0}\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{1}\"\r\n\r\n{2}",
                    boundary,
                    param.Key,
                    param.Value);
                formDataStream.Write(encoding.GetBytes(postData), 0, encoding.GetByteCount(postData));
            }
        }
        string footer = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n";
        formDataStream.Write(encoding.GetBytes(footer), 0, encoding.GetByteCount(footer));
        formDataStream.Position = 0;
        byte[] formData = new byte[formDataStream.Length];
        formDataStream.Read(formData, 0, formData.Length);
        formDataStream.Close();

        return formData;
    }

    public class FileParameter
    {
        public byte[] File { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public string ContentType { get; set; }
        public FileParameter(byte[] file) : this(file, null) { }
        public FileParameter(byte[] file, string filename) : this(file, filename, null) { }
        public FileParameter(byte[] file, string filename, string contenttype)
        {
            File = file;
            FileName = filename;
            ContentType = contenttype;
        }
    }
}
```

Далее уже в самой кнопке кусок кода:

```
Dictionary<string, object> postParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        postParameters.Add("login", cinema.org_login);
        postParameters.Add("password", cinema.org_password);
        postParameters.Add("XMLfile", new Upload.FileParameter(data, fileName, "application/xml"));

        string postURL = "https://....";
        HttpWebResponse webResponse = Upload.MultipartFormDataPost(postURL, postParameters);

        StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
        string fullResponse = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
        webResponse.Close();
        Response.Write(fullResponse);
```